# Create and Read file on Mapped drive C#

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter, mapped-drive

I am trying to create a file on the **mapped drive** but it is giving me an error :

Could not find a part of the path '**Y:\\score\\**' where 'Y' is the mapped drive. There is a folder score in y drive and it has read and write permissions too.

Here is my code:

```
string filePath = "Y:\\score\\";
string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(@filePath))
      {
         foreach (string line in lines)
             outputFile.WriteLine(line);
      }
```

Error comes when I am passing the filepath in the streamwriter.
I am able to do this on my local drive but not on the mapped drive. I am not getting why this error is coming up. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you access Y: drive through Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Mitulátbáti Ya I can access it with explorer

Comment: Are you maybe missing a tag? Is this a web application that is running under a different account from yours?

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be your file path
if you want read file you can use this

this code read all text to string
    File.ReadAllText(filePath);

this code read all line to the string array 
    File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

Comment: I want to write and I cant do it even I am having permissions on that drive

Answer (score 0):

You have no filename. So the `StreamWriter` does not know where to write the lines. You can fix it with

```
string filePath = "Y:\\score\\yourfilename.ext";
string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
        outputFile.WriteLine(line);
}
```

or this

```
string filePath = "Y:\\score\\";
string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(filePath + "yourfilename.ext"))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
        outputFile.WriteLine(line);
}
```

And you have to close the `StreamWriter` after writing.

Comment: I have tried that too.. still no result

Comment: Are you closing the `StreamWriter`after writing the lines?

Comment: Bro it throws error on 'StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(filePath + "yourfilename.ext")' this line itself so their is no point of closing it

Comment: And if you use the UNC-path like `string filePath = @"\\server\share\pathtofile\filename.ext`?

Comment: Ya. Tried that too